# need to convert a string to 2d array

Tags: arrays, string, numpy, argv, sys

I need to convert the following string that I pass as a command-line argument in my python program

`'[[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]'.`
Numpy has something that could be useful for my problem, however, it works only with 1D arrays found in a string. ,

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html

Which options there are to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find one way to solve your problem. 
You can replace your string and remove '[' or ']'. Then you can convert to 1D array and finally reshape to 2D array.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

string=string.replace('[','')
string=string.replace(']','')

array1d=np.fromstring(string,dtype=int,sep=',')
array2d=np.reshape(array1d, (-1, 3))
```

I hope this is help you. Have a good day!